# How do I prove that an uncountable subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ has the in-between property?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The in-between property is that between any two distinct reals in the set, there is another real number. Also, $S$ has no discontinuities. It's not an interval such as $[0, 1] \cup [2, 3]$, for example.

If $S$ were a closed, bounded interval, I can invoke the [nested interval theorem](http://personal.bgsu.edu/~carother/cantor/Nested.html) to show the property holds. I'm not sure how to prove this for unbounded sets such as $\mathbb{R}^+$ or for bounded, open intervals. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The title is inaccurate, since (as you note in the question) there are many uncountable subsets of $\Bbb R$ that don’t have the in-between property. I don’t really understand what you’re asking, since you don’t need the nested intervals theorem to show that a closed, bounded interval has the i-b property: just observe that if $x,y\in[a,b]$ with $x<y$, say, then $x<\frac12(x+y)<y$. The same argument works on any connected subset of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I understand that would work, but I was wondering if there was a more rigorous proof. Also, you can edit the title if you'd like. That's the best I could come up with.

Comment: What I suggested **is** a rigorous proof, assuming that you have in hand the basic facts about arithmetic and order in $\Bbb R$, and I don’t really see how you could prove it using the nested intervals theorem without already assuming it. I would change the title if I were sure of what sets you had in mind. Are you interested just in the ones that you mentioned in the question (rays and open intervals)?

Comment: @Mark Do you maybe mean that any uncountable subset contains *some* $a$,$b$ such that the in-between property holds for $[a,b] \cap S$? (Dunno if this is really the case, but at least it rules out all the obvious counter-examples, and it looks like it should be provable by showing that $S$ is some countable union of countable sets if there are no such $a$,$b$)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Gee I didn't knew the proof of the NI theorem depends on what I'm trying to use it to prove. And yes rays and open/closed intervals is all I care about. The reason I asked for a 'more rigorous'proof is that the text I remember containing this problem didn't seemed like it would ask for a proof if this was such a trivial problem.

Comment: Where are you going to get the endpoints of the nested intervals if you don’t already know that the set has the i-b property?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I see your point. I didn't thought about that either.

Comment: @fgp: It’s not the case: see the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for pointing that out! Nice answer!

Comment: @fgp: You’re welcome, and thank *you*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be any subset of $\Bbb R$ with the property that if $a,b\in A$, and $a<x<b$, then $x\in A$. (Such sets are said to be (order-)convex.) Open intervals, closed intervals, and rays all have this property, as does $\Bbb R$ itself. Now let $a,b\in A$ with $a<b$. Then by elementary properties of the real numbers we know that $a<\frac12(a+b)<b$, and the hypothesis that $A$ is convex ensures that $\frac12(a+b)\in A$. Thus, $A$ has the in-between property. (The more formal term is that $A$ is *densely ordered* by $<$.)

Note that it is not true in general that if $S\subseteq\Bbb R$ is uncountable, then there is a non-trivial interval $I$ such that $S\cap I$ is densely ordered. The [middle-thirds Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) $C$ is a counterexample: if $I$ is a non-trivial interval, and $I\cap C$ contains at least two points, then there are $a,b\in I\cap C$ such that $a<b$ and $(a,b)\cap C=\varnothing$. (Specifically, $a$ and $b$ will be endpoints of one of the deleted open intervals.)